# Convert Latex to Word using Rmarkdown

Tags: ms-word, latex, r-markdown, tex

I have a latex file called mylatex.tex, and I am trying to convert it to a word document.

Does anyone know the step by step process to do this using Rmarkdonw?

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You probably have to use `pandoc`. See e.g. https://medium.com/@zhelinchen91/how-to-convert-from-latex-to-ms-word-with-pandoc-f2045a762293